# Solve an equation involving Exp over the complexes

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I need some help to solve an exponential equation with Mathematica over the complexes.
This is the equation I need to solve. I've already used `FullSimplify`.

```
e^{4-2x-2e^{2-2x}x}x - x =0
```

After defining the whole function as `G[x]`, I used the command

```
rts = Reduce[G[x] == 0, x, Complexes]
```

but the message is

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

I also tryed to use `Solve` and `FindRoot` but it doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Should be `G[x_] := E^(4 - 2 x - 2 E^(2 - 2 x) x) x - x`.

Comment: @cvgmt I've corrected it, but it doesn't work

Comment: isn't $x=0$ a solution?

Answer (score 2):

`NSolve` does the job by

```
NSolve[E^(4 - 2 x - 2 E^(2 - 2 x) x) x - x == 0 &&  Abs[x] <= 10, x, Complexes];Dimensions[%]
```

> `{279, 1}`

Addition. It's strange that

```
NSolve[E^(4 - 2 x - 2 E^(2 - 2 x) x) x - x == 0 && Abs[x] <= 10, x,  Complexes, WorkingPrecision -> 30];Dimesions[%]
```

> `{268, 1}`

and

```
NSolve[E^(4 - 2 x - 2 E^(2 - 2 x) x) x - x == 0 && Re[x] <= 10 && 
Re[x] >= -10 && Im[x] <= 10 && Im[x] >= -10, x, Complexes, 
WorkingPrecision -> 30];Dimensions[%]
```

> `{268, 1}`

I'll try to verify it with Maple.

Addition 2. The verification

```
Table[E^(4 - 2 x - 2 E^(2 - 2 x) x) x - x /. sol[[j]], {j, 1, 268}]
```

confirms all 268 solutions.

Comment: I switched to real variables. The command of Maple `DirectSearch:-SolveEquations([exp(4-2*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*y)*cos(-2*y+2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*y)*x-exp(4-2*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*y)*sin(-2*y+2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*y)*y-x = 0, exp(4-2*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*y)*sin(-2*y+2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*y)*x+exp(4-2*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*y)*cos(-2*y+2*exp(2-2*x)*sin(2*y)*x-2*exp(2-2*x)*cos(2*y)*y)*y-y = 0],`

Comment: `{x >= -10, y >= -10, x <= 10, y <= 10}, AllSolutions, solutions = 100, tolerances = 10^(-11), number = 1200);` finds 52 solutions.

Comment: Test for solutions near Re =1:    Select[solm, (0.999999 < Re[#] < 1.00001 &)] // Length  ->71   , control by  Plot[Re[E^(4 - 2 x - 2 E^(2 - 2 x) x) x - x], {x, 0.9999999, 
  1.00000001}]  showing bit noise near 0. x=1 is a 3. order zero.

Answer (score 0):

What about x=0, x=1? Any other solution has exponent 0, too, so solve

```
2/x-1-e^(2-2x) == 2/x-1 - (e/e^x)^2 ==0
```

The other roots seem to sit on $x =1 + i y$

```
  FindRoot[2/x - 1 - E^2/E^(2 x), {x, 1 + 5 I}]

    {x -> 1. + 4.49341 I}
```

2/(1 + I x) - 1 - E^2/E^(2 (1 + I x)) == 0 // FullSimplify

```
  (x Cos[x] - Sin[x])/(-I + x) == 0


     Plot[x Cos[x] - Sin[x], {x, -120, 120}]
```

[[image: x Cos[x] - Sinx]

The ComplexPlot3D[1/f] exhibits the structure of zeros as poles

[image: complex plot 1]

and a finer resolution

[image: complex plot 2]

Comment: Here are several results of `NSolve`: `{x -> -2.17747124047226705535721254829 + 
   1.98532585029532272308446021163 I}, {x -> 
-1.44292479059622017211280337669 - 
   0.59744381618830898847336446238 I}, {x -> 
-1.44292479059622017211280337669 + 0.59744381618830898847336446238 I}`.